# copying list of delimited files using MSBuild

Tags: .net, asp.net, msbuild

I have string value that in properygroup which is read from config.xml file which outputs as "c:\test\file1;c:\test2\file2" i need to copy that list to destination folder using MSBuild how can I achive that?

```
<Target Name="CopyFiles">  
    <ItemGroup>
        <FilesToCopy 
            Include="@(filesToCopy)"                 
            Exclude="**\*trash*"/>
    </ItemGroup>
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(filesToCopy)"          
         DestinationFiles="@(filesToCopy->'$(Dest)\%(RecursiveDir)\%(Filename)%(Extension)')"          
         ContinueOnError="true"/></Target>
```

in  above code @filesToCopy inclues comma seperated files list.

Comment: Did you notice the syntax error? the above code "Include="@filesToCopy"" should be "Include="@(filesToCopy)""

Comment: yes, its mistaken when copying still no solution found for this

Comment: @DSharper : any updates on this since 2011?

Answer (score 1):

You should not care about semicolon as a delimiter. Copy task of MSBuild works correctly in this case.

It's shown in MSDN documentation sample:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <MySourceFiles Include="a.cs;b.cs;c.cs"/>
</ItemGroup>

<Target Name="CopyFiles">
    <Copy
        SourceFiles="@(MySourceFiles)"
        DestinationFolder="c:\MyProject\Destination"
    />
</Target>
```

from [explanation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3e54c37h.aspx) of MSDN Copy task

Comment: @anton-k, does not work it complain to copy all files as one file name(ie "a.cs;b.cs;c.cs" all as file name)

Comment: @anton-k, your code works if the inlude contains hard coded file names but please see above my code, I want Include="@(FilestoCopy)" which are list of files are dynamic. when i try that it try to copy all files as one file They are actualy read from xml file.

Answer (score 0):

If it's about escaping the semicolon, you would nee to escape it using %3b, refer [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228186%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) for more information

If you need complete information, here you go

```
<ItemGroup>
      <Compile Include="c:\\test\\file1.txt%3Bc:\\test2\\file2.txt" /> 
   </ItemGroup>

<Copy SourceFiles="@(Compile)" DestinationFolder="c:\destination\%(RecursiveDir)">
</Copy>
```

Comment: @Subhash-Dike
 no luck got this error  MSBUILD : warning MSB3021: Unable to copy file "c:\test\file1;c:\test2\file2" to "Dest2\\GettingAroundAirTaxiDe
ccanAviation.aspx.cs". The given path's format is not supported.

Comment: @Subhash-Dike, above anton-k 's code works only when "include" contains hard coded file names paths but i need the file list to come from @filesCopy dynamicaly please see my code.

Answer (score 0):

Treat `filesToCopy` as a Property, not ItemGroup:

```
<FilesToCopy Include="$(filesToCopy)" Exclude="**\*trash*"/>
```

Then when you call the `CopyFiles` target, populate `filesToCopy` with a delimited list of files:

```
msbuild CopyFiles.proj /t:CopyFiles /p:filesToCopy="c:\test\file1;c:\test2\file2"
```

or using the [MSBuild](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z7f65y0d.aspx) task:

```
<Target Name="CallCopyFiles">
    <MSBuild Projects="CopyFiles.proj" Properties="filesToCopy=c:\test\file1;c:\test2\file2"/>
</Target>
```